# Tabbar without any selected tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using an android sherlock action bar with 5 tabs.
I would like to start that app showing the 5 tabs but without any selected tab (I know it could be confusing for the end user...)
Is it possible ? How to do that ?

Comment: even if you try to make no tabs selected, tabs have property of setting default tab selected to the tab of zeroth index

Comment: Yep, agree...without selecting a specific tab, tab0 is selected by default...and it is my pb :) how to avoid this "default mechanism" ? is it possible ?

Comment: Well In my view its not possible but keep trying to get answer may be someone answer to this. I am also waiting for the answer

Comment: I would revise the UI to not do this. That's akin to saying "I want a browser that has a bunch of tabs, but the user cannot see any Web pages".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you want to create something like this but maybe 1 hacky solution...

Create a custom tab that replaces the selected tab drawable image with the unselected tab drawable image. When you click a tab after that it replaces the theme back to the default tab selected.

Edit: I found a post explaining this "trick" further.

['Unselect' a tab in a TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993755/unselect-a-tab-in-a-tabhost)